How to save specific key with redux persit?
I want to just only save key currentLanguage
settingsReducer:
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const initialState = {
  currentLanguage: '',
  test: 'original',
};

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'settings',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setCurrentLanguage(state, { payload }: { payload: string }) {
      state.currentLanguage = payload;
      state.test = payload;
    },
  },
});

const settingsReducer = slice.reducer;

export const {
  setCurrentLanguage,
} = slice.actions;

export default settingsReducer;

Here is my reducer for persist setting:
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import settingsReducer from './settingsReducer';

const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const settingsPersistConfig = {
  key: 'settings',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['currentLanguage'],
};

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  settings: persistReducer(settingsPersistConfig, settingsReducer),
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(
  rootPersistConfig,
  combinedReducer
);

Then App first init and then trigger setCurrentLanguage('en') action, then re open the app to check data, I suppose data should be { currentLanguage: 'en', test: 'original' }, but the result is { currentLanguage: 'en', test: 'en' }.
I try to use blocklist: ['test'] instead of whitelist: ['currentLanguage'] still not working.
How do I achieve it ?

Do you have some previously persisted version of the store that included the state.settings.test state value? Try clearing the storage first, then re-run the app to see what is now actually persisted. If you need more help see if you can provide us a running codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.

Thanks for your response, I don't have set any previously persisted version. I can write a sample repo if you need it.

A running sandbox demo that reproduces the problem should be sufficient.

You only need to change one thing. Blacklist 'settings' in your rootConfig.
const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  blacklist: ['settings'],
};

